# Is it woth for me to invest in SSD and RAM for my 3 1/2 years old laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, memory, windows-8.1, ssd

I have an Samsung Q330 Laptop that I bought in July 2011. The specs are:

CPU: Intel Core i3 380M @ 2.53GHz

GPU: 512MB NVIDIA GeForce 310M

RAM: 4,00GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 532MHz (7-7-7-20)

Storage: 500 GB HDD

OS: Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit

I have in sometime considered buying 2x4 GB RAM for it, and a 128 GB SSD (In case of the SSD I would actually buy a 250 GB SSD for my Desktop and take my current 128 GB SSD in the laptop)

My question is, is it worth it for me to do this, and hope to get another couple of years out of it, or should I just begin saving up for a new one?

Comment: We cannot tell you if its worth it or not since "being worth it" is a concept that will be different to every person.  You will have to decide that on your own.  **Its sort of asking like what is the best type of pie.**  The reasons why the upgrade would be worth it to me might be different from your reasons.  Since your reasons are the only reasons that matter you have to decided if you want to spend the money on your own.

Comment: Ramhound: I was just interested in seeing if anybody had similar experience and could say if it was worth it, or if for example that the CPU would bottleneck my system no matter what etc. EDIT: I see what you mean by your Pie example, point taken

Comment: Of course the age of your CPU should be a concern.  I could go on to explain that you didn't even explain how you use the device, so even if this type of answer wasn't primarily based on an opinion, it would still be extremely hard to answer the question.

Comment: I only use it for school work, running Word, Chrome, Maple, Adobe reader etc.

Comment: We cannot judge whether it's worth for you. It depends entirely on how much money is worth to you, personally.

Answer (score 1):

For work purposes I am using a laptop of a similar age to yours. It's a lenovo X201 born with the following specs:

```
Core i5 520M
2 GB RAM
320 GB HDD
Intel HD graphics
Windows 7 Pro
```

So more or less comparable to your current configuration.

The laptop has been upgraded so that it now runs with:

```
Core i5 520M
4 GB RAM
256 GB SSD (LiteOn LCS-256M6S)
Intel HD graphics
Windows 7 Pro
```

And I must say, I am very happy with the way this 3-4 year old laptop works. I use it exclusively for work, so that is Office365 work, email, web and some light development. In my office I have a dock and external Monitor, keyboard and mouse. So this is actually fully capable as my day-to-day workstation, as well as being sturdy, light and small enough to take with me whereever I go.

I have absolutely no performance issues whatsoever, but please bear in mind that I do not use any graphics intensive applications on this machine.

*My conclusion is*: If you're happy with your laptop generally, but just need a bit faster performance, then you should definitely go for the upgrade. As the difference of the SSD is enormous.

If you have any problems at all (size, weight, build quality etc.) with your current machine, however, I would strongly advise you to look into buying a new laptop, that will solve those problems for you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I post answer. I have ThinkPad T400. It is about 5yo and it was worth for me. And it is up on you. If you care well of your laptop and has good components it should be working many years. If you are satisfied on using it and don't want to replace it with new one I suggest it to you. It will bring you new joy of using your laptop - I mean SSD. In case of RAM I had 2GB and upgraded on 4GB and it is enough for me. Depends on how you use your laptop.

But be careful with SSD it is fine when you use SSD as System disk or backup data which you have on it. SSD's are not dying like HDD which will also warn you. SSD just die and won't let you know of it. I lost some of my data from school this way. It is fine if you will use your 500GB HDD as data disk where you can store some files, movies, music, photos, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Overall the laptop is not old enough to be "worthless"

Depending on what you do with the laptop I would suggest trying out an SSD first and add RAM later if you find that you are constantly swapping memory from the RAM to the disk.

If you plan on gaming then I think you and I both know that the Nvidia 310M is worthless for that.

If you upgrade to an SSD alone then I would easily expect you can get another 2-4 years out of it before it truly feels underpowered.